# Get First Option on Text on Dropdown After Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins

**EDIT 1** - BRIEF

This is how it is. https://ibb.co/9WY5gLL it has a datatable, which is sorted according to dropdown selections and there is a button to reset the sortings. the reset part is working fine except the text in dropdown is not changing. but if I remove the slect box class in dropdown HTML all working fine.

```
//DROPDOWN HTML
<select name="status" id="status" class="statusbox SlectBox form-control">
    <?php echo loadStatus(); ?>
</select>

//DATATABLE
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table= $('#tableone').DataTable( {
     "serverSide":  true,
     "ajax": {
        url  :"sonme.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : function(data){
        var status = $('#status').val();
        data.status= status;
      }
    } );
} );

//TABLE FILTER
$('#status').change(function(){
    table.draw();
});

//RESET TABLE
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $("select.statusbox").val($("select.statusbox option:first").val()).change();
});

//PHP RETURNED BY AJAX CALL
function location(){
    global $con;
    $output.= '<option value="_allCity">All Results</option>';
    $_selectquery= "SELECT * FROM _tableone";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $_selectquery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output.= '<option value = "'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying when you do `$('#_location').val('_allCity')` you don't see *"All results"* displayed? Really not clear what the problem is here

Comment: Note that you don't set text on a `<select>`, just value. Provide an html/js only example that demonstrates your issue. Your php code is not relevant here. See [mre]

Comment: Try : `$("#_location option:contains('All Results')").prop("selected",true).trigger("change")` .

Comment: @Swati Events don't trigger on option in some browsers. That seems like a convoluted work around also

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right. its like this. if I have the class SlectBox, the dropdown selected text doesn't change when I reset. If I remove the class, it is working fine.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Setting the default value on a select should always work

Comment: I will edit the question @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl Please read the question again. its edited. and it doesn't seems to work setting the default value.

Comment: There is something going on you aren't showing us. Are you using any sort of `<select>` plugin script? Are you removing the class `statusbox `? Is the select html getting replaced at any time? There simply isn't enough shown to reproduce your issue

Comment: @RoshanZaid Maybe add a few screenshots of the DevTools (F12) structure around those elements - if telling the story in words doesn't work, tell the story in pictures (or hosted video)

Comment: let me host in JS Bin or Fiddle

Comment: @cssyphus https://streamable.com/fdz5q1 Please check the link for what should be achieved.  it is about changing the dropdown selected text after resetting the table.

Comment: @charlietfl https://streamable.com/fdz5q1 Please check the link for what should be achieved.  it is about changing the dropdown selected text after resetting the table.

Comment: @Swati https://streamable.com/fdz5q1 Please check the link for what should be achieved. it is about changing the dropdown selected text after resetting the table.

Comment: Try just using the id of the select and also make sure the button event is working at the time you click it

Comment: @charlietfl still the same. No changes on select text after button is pressed.

Comment: Is button event working? Provide sample of html in the select itself (rendered options) so we can reproduce the problem. Either the button event is not working  or selector is wrong for select or something else is also working on the select

Comment: Yes, of course button event is working. and the table shows all once the button is pressed. just the select's text is not changing.

Comment: @charlietfl check this out. this is when the class - statusbox is removed in Select - https://streamable.com/g6ll2s

Comment: Hard to help more without a **runnable** [mre] that demonstrates this and can be inspected in dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl Please check this link, https://jsfiddle.net/wj03bhLe/

its almost similar to this. You click reset, if something is selected in dropdown, it should reset the value and text of dropdown.

Comment: Ah as I suspected as possibility you are using a select replacement plugin and need to use the api for that to make the reset change. I asked about this above

Comment: @charlietfl I am using a jquery plugin for selectors and in the HTML the class of it was mentioned. thought it would be sufficient for the issue. As I have stated, if the plugin class is removed. dropdown text is changing. if its added. the table is resetting but not dropdown's text. What should I provide more?

Comment: You need to use the plugin API to change the value. Using a plugin is considerably more involved than just a class difference

Comment: @charlietfl Please join chat if possible https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233438/get-text-of-selected-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is the sumo select jquery plugin, all what I had to is reviewing the documentation.

This line - `$('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.reload();` reset the dropdown and value as the default. Please check the doc: https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/